# Javascript to change color of all spans with certain ID

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I have the following code to change the color of text with a certain spanID. Currently, it only changes the first instance of the span and on subsequent instances. Any suggestions?

```
<script>

function spanColor() {
    var x = document.getElementById('someId');
    x.style.color = '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);

}
</script>
```

Comment: You mean you have many spans with the same _unique_ ID? You should look into classes. IDs are supposed to be unique in the whole DOM.

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document. Use a class and a function that returns a collection, such as `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Use a class, select all by the class, loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all the needed elements you should use `querySelectorAll(#id)`
But as you saw in the comments - ID is not the best way to get more than one item.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ID for a ClassName and use `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");`

So your code should look like this:

```
<script>

function spanColor() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('someClassname');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.color = '#'+Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
    }

}
</script>
```